# Short pin 5 for boot, and also use I2C bus on pin 5

Tags: gpio, i2c

I'm building a little audio streamer box, using a Rpi4.  This box has a few buttons, such as play/pause, next track, previous track, etc, as well as a power button that I want to use for turning it on (by shorting pins 5 and 6) and for sending a shutdown command.

I'm also using a small OLED display that is connected to the I2C bus (pins 3 and 5).

Is there a way to either move the I2C bus to other pins, so I can free up pin 5 for the power button, or can I somehow safely use pin 5 for both the I2C bus and the power button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot **share** pin 5, but the RPi 4B has *several* hardware-based i2c channels, and at least one software-based i2c (`i2c-gpio`), available for use. These GPIO channels are listed and defined in your local `/boot/overlays/README` file; there's also a copy of this [README file on RPi's GitHub site](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/blob/master/boot/overlays/README). These additional channels are declared and configured in your `/boot/config.txt` file as *overlays*.

I was forced to relocate my RTC from `i2c1` because I also needed to use GPIO3 for another purpose. I chose to move my RTC from `i2c1` to `i2c0`, and it has worked fine for months now. I wrote up [the procedure I followed on this GitHub page.](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiFormulae/blob/master/MoveRTCfromI2C1-to-I2C0.md)

Note that not all of the RPi's alternative `i2c` channels have pullup resistors (`i2c0` & `i2c1` have *on-board* pullups), and they may need to be added if your OLED display does not have them.

Comment: I read this and your GitHub page and was intrigued. I haven't been able to use i2c0 for years. After reading the (rather confusing) `/overlays/README` I tried `dtoverlay=i2c_vc=on` on Bullseye and found `/dev/i2c-2` showed something on address 50 but no i2c0.  I note I have been successful in using uart2 on GPIO0,1

Comment: @Milliways: IIUC, you've tried using `i2c0` on Buster also, but it wouldn't work?? I've reviewed some of this just now: The `i2c0` configuration is still in use on my RPi4/Buster/Lite machine. I didn't try it on my RPi3B+/Buster/Lite. I've recently "upgraded" RPi3B+ to Bullseye. Would it "*advance the cause*" if I tried to use `i2c0` on RPi3B+/Bullseye/Lite... would that tell us anything?

Comment: I just tried on Pi4 running Buster. This shows i2c-22 i2c-0 i2c-10 but nothing connected - on Bullseye (Pi3B+) shows i2c-2 with address 50. In both cases no I²C devices actually connect to GPIO 0,1

Comment: @Milliways: I never tried it with nothing connected to the bus - in my case the slave device was an RTC w/ pullups on SDA & SCL. How would it even work with nothing on the other end of the bus? I mean, there's got to be something connected to get a result from `i2cdetect`. Are you referring to the output from `ls /dev/*i2c*`? If so, I think that only means the kernel has [*provisioned* a node](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241173/how-are-dev-linux-files-created) in the device tree. Not sure we're on the same page???

Answer (score 0):

The only pins usable for hardware I²C are 3,5.

You should be able to also use pin 5 to reboot (but AFAIK not shutdown).

See [Will pulling pin 5 low will make the pi boot up again](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/19754/8697)

You can use other pins to shutdown [dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/77918/8697).

Frankly there is little point. Reboot only works after a soft shutdown, which leaves most of the Pi running but still [using significant power](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100125/8697).

Comment: So when pin 5 is already being used for I2C, there's no way to short it to turn on the RPi?

Comment: @starfly re read my answer which says no such thing.